# Standard UX process or Project wise ?

Tags: ux-field, ux-integration

Should a UX process be standard for all projects or should it be defined according to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UX Process should be set based on the various factors, like

- Cost of the project - Cost may not afford to spend on research and
  usability test hiring the real users.
- Access to the real users
- Project time lines - UCD process should be aligned before the
  development process starts. 
  and so on...

Most of the projects which are of small scale or medium budgeted would not afford to spend on research as there objective could be existence in the market.

Based on project and the objective the UX process should be planned.